# How to enable branch hints in Mac OS git?

Tags: macos, git, terminal

In windows, when I use git bash, and for example want to to checkout to some branch, hitting tab shows me all the branches, or fills the branch name if I have written part of it. In my Mac OS, when I use git from my terminal, these features are disabled. Is there a way to enable them, and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install [git-autocomplete](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) which can be get with [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation):

1. Install Git and bash-completion: brew install git bash-completion (Note: If this install fails with a 404 error, and you already have git installed, just remove the git part of this brew install)
2. Add bash-completion to your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: sure) just have to wait 5 minutes :D )

Answer (score 0):

Note: that same [git completion](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) just got more complete with Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)

See [commit 49416ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49416ad22aa917178f306859a5bab60311166a9f) (24 Aug 2016) by [Chris Packham (`cpackham`)](https://github.com/cpackham).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a229a30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a229a30f8a3f52343f52e8691f7261fe95cb4cf1), 10 Oct 2016)</sup>

> The command-line completion script (in `contrib/`) learned to complete "`git cmd ^mas<HT>`" to complete the [negative end of reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#_description) to "`git cmd ^master`".